# AWS lambda python approach/code required to make variable global on every call

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I need an approach in AWS lambda to resolve a issue please help

**What am I doing now:**

Inside lambda handler function I am taking data from athena and performing some logic, also taking data from kinesis performing some logic. lambda handler is invoked every 20 sec

This is pseudo code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    query = query to get data from athena
    df = pd.DataFrame(query)
    ###Some processing logic from by taking data from kinesis###
```

**My problem is**

The data that I take from athena will change only once in a day. So every time when lambda handler is invoked it is unnecessarily querying to athena which is inefficient

**What I need**

I need some solution approach/code to "query athena and put in dataframe as global scope" so each time when lambda handler is triggered it will make use of global variable.

Answer (score 0):

There are **no persistent global variables** within lambda itself. The only limited persistence of data that you can count for is through  [AWS Lambda execution environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html):

> **Objects declared outside** of the function's handler method remain initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in subsequent invocations. We recommend adding logic in your code to check if a connection exists before creating a new one.

However, this is not reliable and short lived. Thus the only way for you not to query Athena often, is to **store the query results outside of lambda function**.

Depending on the nature and amount of the data to be stored, a **common choices** to ensure persistence of the data between lambda function invocations are S3, EFS, DynamoDB, SSM Parameter Store and ElasticCache.

Comment: Hi March, Thank you for the response . We have increased timeout and memory for lambda then it has worked. Now,  the variables declared outside the function able to access within the handler in subsequent calls

Comment: @user3292373 Yes, you can access them as you would normally do in python.